# Running specific test step in SoapUI based on testSuite property

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new to scripting and could use some help. I have an issues regarding SoapUI groovy script I could use help with.

I need a script that will let me run specific testStep in testCase based on value of testSuite property ('CC1' is name of property) with 5 possibilities. I guess switch/case could be used, but don't know how to write it properly.

At the moment I tried using this:

```
def CC1 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("CC1")
log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("CC1")

switch(CC1)  
{  
  case ~/^[H1]+$/: testRunner.runTestStepByName( "PT02_H1" ); break;  
  case ~/^[Y5]+$/: testRunner.runTestStepByName( "PT02_Y5" ); break;  
  case ~/^[Q2]+$/: testRunner.runTestStepByName( "PT02_Q2" ); break;  
  case ~/^[T5]+$/: testRunner.runTestStepByName( "PT02_T5" ); break;  
  default : testRunner.runTestStepByName( "PT02_AQ" );  
}
```

But doesn't run the desired step.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Why two questions clubbed into one?

Comment: I edited my post for one question.

Comment: How does your test case look like? Is the above groovy script and other 5 test steps, one of which you wanted to execute, in the same test case? Have you looked about `Conditional goto` test step?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following script (run from groovyTestStep):

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def testCase = testRunner.testCase;
def testStep = null;
def CC1 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("CC1")
log.info testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("CC1")

switch(CC1)  
{  
  case ~/^[H1]+$/: testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName( "PT02_H1" ); break;  
  case ~/^[Y5]+$/: testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName( "PT02_Y5" ); break;  
  case ~/^[Q2]+$/: testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName( "PT02_Q2" ); break;  
  case ~/^[T5]+$/: testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName( "PT02_T5" ); break;  
  default : testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName( "PT02_AQ" );  
}
testRunner = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner(testCase, null);
testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);
testStep.run(testRunner, testStepContext);
log.info "TEST OK:"+testStep.getName();
```